# 整数の入った列を横展開して1,0に変換したい

Tags: r

以下のようなデータフレームdfがあるのですが、

```
id category
1   3
2   2
3   3
4   1
5   2
6   2
```

これを

```
id category1 category2 category3
1   0         0         1
2   0         1         0
3   0         0         1
4   1         0         0
5   0         1         0
6   0         1         0
```

のような形にしたいと考えています。
現在はこれを

```
df <- tidyr::spread(df,category,category) #横展開
df.id <- df[,1] #そのままやるとid列も1になってしまうため分離
df.other <- df[,-1]
df.other[!is.na(df.other)] <- 1
df.other[is.na(df.other)] <- 0
df <- cbind(df.id,df.other)
```

としているのですが、もう少しスマートな方法はないでしょうか？
どなたかご教授お願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

スマートかどうかは分かりませんが、、以下は `apply` を使う場合です。

```
> df[paste('category', sort(unique(df$category)), sep='')] <- 0
> data.frame(t(apply(df, 1,
    function(r){
      r[paste('category', r['category'], sep='')] <- 1
      r[-c(2)]
    })))

  id category1 category2 category3
1  1         0         0         1
2  2         0         1         0
3  3         0         0         1
4  4         1         0         0
5  5         0         1         0
6  6         0         1         0
```

`apply(df, 1, ...)` とすることでデータフレームを行ごとに処理します。また、`r[-c(2)]` でデータフレームの `category` カラムを削除しています。

Answer (score 1):

その作業はdummy変数の作成などと呼ばれ、`dummies` や `caret` 等のパッケージがそれ用の関数を持っています。私の一押しは `makedummies` パッケージです。

```
# install.packages("makedummies")
library(makedummies)

df$category <- as.factor(df$category)  # makedummies()はファクターを1,0に横展開します
makedummies(df, basal_level = TRUE)    # basal_level = T で第1カテゴリ列も作成されます

#   id category_1 category_2 category_3
# 1  1          0          0          1
# 2  2          0          1          0
# 3  3          0          0          1
# 4  4          1          0          0
# 5  5          0          1          0
# 6  6          0          1          0
```

Comment: `makedummies` パッケージのCRAN登録に伴い一部修正を行いました。

Answer (score 1):

`base`の`model.matrix`が使える:

```
x = data.frame(id = 1:6, category = c(3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2))
```

`category`を`factor`に変えよう:

```
x$category = factor(x$category)

model.matrix(~catgory - 1, data = x)

#   category1 category2 category3
# 1         0         0         1
# 2         0         1         0
# 3         0         0         1
# 4         1         0         0
# 5         0         1         0
# 6         0         1         0
```

`-1`は「部分を除け」と示して、すべて`category`のレベルを含みます。

Answer (score 1):

{tidyverse}だとこうでしょうか

```
tidyr::spread(df,category,category) %>%
  dplyr::mutate_each(funs(ifelse(is.na(.), 0, 1)), -id)
```

Answer (score 1):

makedummiesパッケージの作者です。
ダミー変数に変換したい列が複数ある場合にはmakedummiesを試してみて下さい。

つい最近CRANに登録されました。

Comment: CRAN登録の情報ありがとうございます、私の解答を一部変更させていただきました。登録おめでとうございます。

Comment: 反映して頂きありがとうございます。